# How do I set an outputArument in Dataweave

Tags: variables, mule, datamapper, dataweave

I am using mule 3.7.3 and want to be able to set an outputArgument like I did in Datamapper to be used in java code to aggregate the scatter gather result.  How do I do this?

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    dept: payload01.name,
    deptId: payload01.id
})
```

Comment: What exactly you mean by **outputArgument**?

Answer (score 0):

When you set an output argument in datamapper, it becomes flow variable after data mapper executes.

In dataweave, you define transformation and it go as payload and/or variables.

In below Sample, I have am doing two transformations in Dataweave.

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">

            <dw:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    "key":payload[0..3]
}]]></dw:set-payload>

            <dw:set-variable variableName="myOutputVar"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    key2:'sample var'
}]]></dw:set-variable>

        </dw:transform-message>
```

Here, I have two

- < dw:set-payload>: The output of this transformation will be set as a payload to next transformer in flow.
- < dw:set-variable> : It specifies an unique variableName attribute. The output of this transformation will be set as a flowVariable with key specified in variableName attribute. This is where you can relate **datamapper outputArguments to DataWeave.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  If I want to set the variable as a string and not a map how can I do that?

Comment: Look at the dataweave canonical model -  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation#literal-expressions.

Comment: <dw:set-variable variableName="myOutputVar"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
'My String'
]]></dw:set-variable>

Answer (score 0):

In data weave in the output side just in drop down choose new target
In new target choose variable or property and they will be set as a string.

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="4b36924c-a436-40b5-ad3b-f13acd1ec963" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
}]]></dw:set-payload>
            <dw:set-variable variableName="NewVariable"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.Input]]></dw:set-variable>
        </dw:transform-message>
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you want is to return a string variable instead of a payload map, you need to both, set a payload that you need to transform "" and set the return variable ""

Also, you can do something like this to return a string

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
  message: "return value"
}
```